# Angular filter data by date

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

I have a json as follows which i am receiving using an angular service:

```
[
    {
        "id": 2,
        "order_status": "R",
        "order_date": "2015-09-12T07:58:24.733834Z",
        "update_timestamp": "2015-10-05T04:22:44.904227Z"
    },
    {
        "id": 8,
        "order_status": "D",
        "order_date": "2015-09-18T03:46:50.469051Z",
        "update_timestamp": "2015-09-23T19:19:31.658001Z"
    }
]
```

I am receiving this data into a variable `$scope.order_items` and i am filtering them by `order_status` column:

```
$scope.order_items = data;
$scope.received = ($scope.order_items.filter(function(item) { return (item.order_status == 'R');}));
$scope.delivered = ($scope.order_items.filter(function(item) { return (item.order_status == 'D');}));
```

Now i am trying to filter the data by the column `order_date` such that i get all today's data entries into a separate variable. How do i achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT**: Just realized that you don't actually have a Date() object for the order_date so you'll have to create one before doing the == check belo.

There are a number of good Javascript Date manipulation libraries available(rather than doing the setHours(...) trick below, but something like this is what you want.

```
       var Date today = new Date();
       var todaysDates = $filter('filter')($scope.order_items, function(item) {

          if(item.order_date.setHours(0,0,0,0) == today.setHours(0,0,0,0)) {
              return true;
          } else {
              return false;
          }

        });
```